# How to make intermittent lines to represent periods of presence and absence on a given line during it's length on Multi Axis chart?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a multiaxis chart that represent the historic statistic of positions for mexican soccer teams during the whole existance of the Mexican league itself.

Some of those teams either disappear, change identity or have bad results and are downgraded to 2nd League.

However, Multilinear Axis chart seems to represent only constant lines, thus I cannot nullify a period or epoch in the chart for some teams.

Example:
http://eliezer.rocks/ligamx/historico.php

Note: since only 20 positions exist in the league, and in the chart, I assign a obviously off-the-limits for teams whom disappeared. Such as position 25, but this is not the best. Maybe we should be able to represent periods on the charts.

Went through documentation, tried myself to understand the code and add the feature but failed.

http://eliezer.rocks/ligamx/historico.php

It's all unencoded, unencrypted.

As a Chart.js user 
I would like to be able to nullify periods for a line in multi axis chart,
So I can represent use case of a line with epochs or periods.

Answer (score 0):

Oh deer, you just need to put null values in the json to make lines disappear for an occurrence.

```
    {
                label: 'CELAYA',
                borderColor: window.chartColors.Color2,
                backgroundColor: window.chartColors.Color2,
                fill: false,
                data: [
            null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,-17,null,-16,-16,-18,-16,-15,-14,-11,-8,-11,-17,-16,-17,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,                 ],
                yAxisID: 'y-axis-42',
            },
```